# Cryptopals challenge 4 concern

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

i am not getting the desired results for Cryptopals challenge 4 set 1.

The concept of the program to check to see if any of these 300ish strings have been XORd by a single character. So with a brute force, my solution is take every string, XOR it with every character on the keyboard, and check to see if any of these results produce an english sentence. if not, then check the next string. Here is my code:

```
MY_DICT = {}
index = 0
my_plaintext = "Now that the party is jumping"

#fills the dictionary with hex strings from the txt file
with open("hexstrings.txt") as f:
    my_list = f.readlines()
    for x in my_list:
        MY_DICT[index] = x.rstrip('\n')
        index = index + 1

i=0
input() #this is just here to help me keep track of where i am when running it

#this loop fills possible_plaintext with all the possible 255 XORs of the i'th string
#of the dictionary that was previously filler from the txt file

for i in range(326):
    possible_plaintexts =  brute_force_singlechar_xor(MY_DICT[i])
    print(possible_plaintexts)
    if possible_plaintexts == my_plaintext:  #line of concern
        print("ya found it yay :) ")
```

Im sure that myBruteForce function works because it worked properly on the last problem where i XORd every possible char against a string. and i also know that the plaintext is the one provided bc i saw the solution. im just not sure why my program isnt recognizing that the plaintext is not in the dictionary.

(i am aware that using a scoring system to score every string to see if its close to english would be easier, but this is the way i chose to do it for now until i figure out how to get my scoring function to work /:  )

Answer (score 0):

How is your dictionary "possible_plaintexts" like when you print it?
Can you spot the solution in the printed text? How is it printed?

The decrypted string should also have a '\n' character.